# How to enforce Kafka consumer to use certain version of schema?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro, confluent-schema-registry

We have multiple versions of schemas of a topic, and messages are in AVRO format.

From what I understand, when a consumer receives an AVRO message, the message itself contains an id which will be used to retrieve schema from schema registry, and cached locally for future ref.

I am curious to know if there's a way to by-pass this id lookup, and always use one pre-obtained schema (e.g. latest one) to parse all messages on consumer side?

The deserializer we use is `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer`

Answer (score 1):

`use.latest.version=true` is one config option for the serializer, but there's no setting to use a specific version; the only way I can think of would be to consume using ByteArrayDeserializer, then manually modify the ID, then pass that result into the KafkaAvroDeserializer to get the record with that specific schema ID